# Creation of namespace is forbidden for default user, tring to install meshery for EKS

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, servicemesh

I executed the below command:

```
kubectl create namespace meshery
```

And I get an error like below:

```
Error from server (Forbidden): namespaces is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:default" cannot create resource "namespaces" in API group "" at the cluster scope
```

The Steps I executed before that were as follows:

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-43 ~]$ kubectl create serviceaccount meshery
Error from server (AlreadyExists): serviceaccounts "meshery" already exists
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-43 ~]$ kubectl create clusterrolebinding meshery-binding --clusterrole=cluster-admin \
>  --serviceaccount=default:meshery
error: failed to create clusterrolebinding: clusterrolebindings.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "meshery-binding" already exists
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-43 ~]$ kubectl get secrets
NAME                               TYPE                                  DATA   AGE
bookinfo-details-token-tm654       kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      40h
bookinfo-productpage-token-lr9zq   kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      40h
bookinfo-ratings-token-2gc5h       kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      40h
bookinfo-reviews-token-8k76p       kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      40h
default-token-zwx6k                kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      3d
meshery-token-x94qk                kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      3d
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-43 ~]$ kubectl describe secret default-token-zwx6k
Name:         default-token-zwx6k
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  kubernetes.io/service-account.name: default
              kubernetes.io/service-account.uid: 33a3496d-db4c-4fb3-b634-204560210f90

Type:  kubernetes.io/service-account-token

Data
====
ca.crt:     1025 bytes
namespace:  7 bytes
token:      eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IlJ4RV82SFR1Q3ltQVp2dHZBMEpNd2RkaTVqM2hQOHB3SURIZDRoVW9lRGcifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJrdWJlcm5ldGVzL3NlcnZpY2VhY2NvdW50Iiwia3ViZXJuZXRlcy5pby9zZXJ2aWNlYWNjb3VudC9uYW1lc3BhY2UiOiJkZWZhdWx0Iiwia3ViZXJuZXRlcy5pby9zZXJ2aWNlYWNjb3VudC9zZWNyZXQubmFtZSI6ImRlZmF1bHQtdG9rZW4tend4NmsiLCJrdWJlcm5ldGVzLmlvL3NlcnZpY2VhY2NvdW50L3NlcnZpY2UtYWNjb3VudC5uYW1lIjoiZGVmYXVsdCIsImt1YmVybmV0ZXMuaW8vc2VydmljZWFjY291bnQvc2VydmljZS1hY2NvdW50LnVpZCI6IjMzYTM0OTZkLWRiNGMtNGZiMy1iNjM0LTIwNDU2MDIxMGY5MCIsInN1YiI6InN5c3RlbTpzZXJ2aWNlYWNjb3VudDpkZWZhdWx0OmRlZmF1bHQifQ.TdvS4w0i0ky4dWoqrCL4PrggkpbdxlwqAhPpVQuItqCIPThB_IbCbve6KCMKSePNhO6Kw_TV9TiCiZMSzoqc0T_4PnrAcj48IafKi8_JbcNACeoR7KbSNnYigL8Ou1uQFmcM2Wu2FVjaaCg1tVUC4T0oCPH9MQLnyXIbs7lZk6Ip0Cu0qm-86XyyRSdg5m6qc9FkJqZJfiu65EOmNZhhDbx452PmZ4Ag73WcJKCTDMfZBDq5FiQM4eZtpgTjFec0980JpoBqQppVYOyjSh5sjKqkJNo-BcRDiVcAJRM23gDF5Xu4OABvWX3-cgpwb0cdZ0Xx-RK3xomzSu2Qstn5pw
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-43 ~]$ kubectl config set-credentials meshery --token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IlJ4RV82SFR1Q3ltQVp2dHZBMEpNd2RkaTVqM2hQOHB3SURIZDRoVW9lRGcifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJrdWJlcm5ldGVzL3NlcnZpY2VhY2NvdW50Iiwia3ViZXJuZXRlcy5pby9zZXJ2aWNlYWNjb3VudC9uYW1lc3BhY2UiOiJkZWZhdWx0Iiwia3ViZXJuZXRlcy5pby9zZXJ2aWNlYWNjb3VudC9zZWNyZXQubmFtZSI6ImRlZmF1bHQtdG9rZW4tend4NmsiLCJrdWJlcm5ldGVzLmlvL3NlcnZpY2VhY2NvdW50L3NlcnZpY2UtYWNjb3VudC5uYW1lIjoiZGVmYXVsdCIsImt1YmVybmV0ZXMuaW8vc2VydmljZWFjY291bnQvc2VydmljZS1hY2NvdW50LnVpZCI6IjMzYTM0OTZkLWRiNGMtNGZiMy1iNjM0LTIwNDU2MDIxMGY5MCIsInN1YiI6InN5c3RlbTpzZXJ2aWNlYWNjb3VudDpkZWZhdWx0OmRlZmF1bHQifQ.TdvS4w0i0ky4dWoqrCL4PrggkpbdxlwqAhPpVQuItqCIPThB_IbCbve6KCMKSePNhO6Kw_TV9TiCiZMSzoqc0T_4PnrAcj48IafKi8_JbcNACeoR7KbSNnYigL8Ou1uQFmcM2Wu2FVjaaCg1tVUC4T0oCPH9MQLnyXIbs7lZk6Ip0Cu0qm-86XyyRSdg5m6qc9FkJqZJfiu65EOmNZhhDbx452PmZ4Ag73WcJKCTDMfZBDq5FiQM4eZtpgTjFec0980JpoBqQppVYOyjSh5sjKqkJNo-BcRDiVcAJRM23gDF5Xu4OABvWX3-cgpwb0cdZ0Xx-RK3xomzSu2Qstn5pw
User "meshery" set.
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-43 ~]$ kubectl config set-context --current --user=meshery
Context "arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:632078958246:cluster/icluster1" modified.
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-43 ~]$ kubectl config view --minify --flatten >  config_aws_eks.yaml
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-43 ~]$ cat config_aws_eks.yaml
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: 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
    server: https://BE1866C372B4FCB9E011E90A2BA78F79.gr7.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com
  name: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:632078958246:cluster/icluster1
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:632078958246:cluster/icluster1
    user: meshery
  name: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:632078958246:cluster/icluster1
current-context: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:632078958246:cluster/icluster1
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: meshery
  user:
    token: eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IlJ4RV82SFR1Q3ltQVp2dHZBMEpNd2RkaTVqM2hQOHB3SURIZDRoVW9lRGcifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJrdWJlcm5ldGVzL3NlcnZpY2VhY2NvdW50Iiwia3ViZXJuZXRlcy5pby9zZXJ2aWNlYWNjb3VudC9uYW1lc3BhY2UiOiJkZWZhdWx0Iiwia3ViZXJuZXRlcy5pby9zZXJ2aWNlYWNjb3VudC9zZWNyZXQubmFtZSI6ImRlZmF1bHQtdG9rZW4tend4NmsiLCJrdWJlcm5ldGVzLmlvL3NlcnZpY2VhY2NvdW50L3NlcnZpY2UtYWNjb3VudC5uYW1lIjoiZGVmYXVsdCIsImt1YmVybmV0ZXMuaW8vc2VydmljZWFjY291bnQvc2VydmljZS1hY2NvdW50LnVpZCI6IjMzYTM0OTZkLWRiNGMtNGZiMy1iNjM0LTIwNDU2MDIxMGY5MCIsInN1YiI6InN5c3RlbTpzZXJ2aWNlYWNjb3VudDpkZWZhdWx0OmRlZmF1bHQifQ.TdvS4w0i0ky4dWoqrCL4PrggkpbdxlwqAhPpVQuItqCIPThB_IbCbve6KCMKSePNhO6Kw_TV9TiCiZMSzoqc0T_4PnrAcj48IafKi8_JbcNACeoR7KbSNnYigL8Ou1uQFmcM2Wu2FVjaaCg1tVUC4T0oCPH9MQLnyXIbs7lZk6Ip0Cu0qm-86XyyRSdg5m6qc9FkJqZJfiu65EOmNZhhDbx452PmZ4Ag73WcJKCTDMfZBDq5FiQM4eZtpgTjFec0980JpoBqQppVYOyjSh5sjKqkJNo-BcRDiVcAJRM23gDF5Xu4OABvWX3-cgpwb0cdZ0Xx-RK3xomzSu2Qstn5pw
```

**Goal to accomplish:**
Install and Configure Meshery for EKS Cluster.

Reference links:

1. https://meshery.layer5.io/docs/installation/platforms/eks
2. https://github.com/layer5io/meshery/blob/master/docs/pages/installation/kubernetes.md

EDIT: I set kube context as per your advice, but still not getting there:

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-43 ~]$ kubectl get users
Please enter Username:

[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-43 ~]$ kubectl get ns
Please enter Username:
```

Comment: My suspicion is that because you've set before context for `--user=meshery` the user does not have enough privileges to create namespace. Can you try to set context for your default/admin user and try to create that namespace? Example: `kubectl config set-context --current --user=kubernetes-admin`

Comment: Yeah did exactly as per your suggestion still not charm.

Comment: But, I added cluster-admin role still why it cannot create the namespace I wonder

Comment: I have followed the instructions and I noticed that you used `default-token-...` instead of `meshery-token-...` as suggest point 3,4 in the first document. Can you please verify that? For me this all works just fine.

Comment: Did you get a chance to check my previous suggestions? @learner

Answer (score 0):

I have followed your steps and the  instructions that you provided and I managed to reproduce your issue:

```
➜  ~ kubectl create namespace meshery

Error from server (Forbidden): namespaces is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:meshery" cannot create resource "namespaces" in API group "" at the cluster scope
```

Switching the context back does allow me to create that desired namespace which leads to conclusion that the `meshery` roles are not properly setup:

```sh
    ➜  ~ kubectl config set-context --current --user=minikube
    Context "minikube" modified.
    ➜  ~ kubectl create namespace meshery                    
    
    namespace/meshery created
```

After careful looking into the issue i found out that `ClusterRole` name referenced in `ClusterRoleBinding` is incorrect and serviceaccount is referenced inside the `ClusterRole` name:

```yaml
    ➜  ~ kubectl get clusterrolebinding meshery-binding -oyaml
    apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
    kind: ClusterRoleBinding
    metadata:
      managedFields:
      - apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
        manager: kubectl-create
        operation: Update
      name: meshery-binding
    roleRef:
      apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
      kind: ClusterRole
      name: cluster-admin--serviceaccount=default:meshery
```

Which means that the command from the documentation is incorrectly written since there should be space between `cluster-admin` and `--serviceaccount=default:meshery`.

```sh
kubectl create clusterrolebinding meshery-binding --clusterrole=cluster-admin\--serviceaccount=default:meshery
```

Once I have corrected the space:

```sh
kubectl create clusterrolebinding meshery-binding --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=default:meshery
```

You can see that the `ClusterRoleBinding` looks correct now:

```yaml
➜  ~ kubectl get clusterrolebinding meshery-binding -oyaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
    manager: kubectl-create
    operation: Update
  name: meshery-binding
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: meshery
  namespace: default
```

Now switching context to `meshery` works as expected:

```sh
➜  ~ kubectl config set-context --current --user=meshery 
Context "minikube" modified.
```

```sh
➜  ~ kubectl create namespace meshery 
namespace/meshery created
```